# Capture all the search results and href in Google search in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, excel, vba, dom, web-scraping

I developed a VBA script for web scraping to capture all the search results and href in Google search.

It is working in IE 11.
When I distribute the file to IE 9 users, the info can't be captured in Excel.

As I inspect elements in both IE version and compare, I can see the different HTML source code.

What can I do in the coding to be compatible for both IE versions?

```vb
Sub Google()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim url As String
    Dim search As String
    
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim x2 As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim LR As Integer
    
    x = 3
    LR = Sheets("Search Form(Google)").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For y = x To LR
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
        url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="
    
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.navigate url
    
        Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Loop
        
        search_name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Search Form(Google)").Cells(y, 1).Value
            
        'ie.document.getElementsByName("q")(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Search Form(Google)").Cells(y, 1).Value
        IE.document.getElementsByName("q")(0).Value = search
    
        Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    
        IE.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).submit
            
        Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            
    'Next
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Search Form(Google)").Cells(y, 3).Value = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("r")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getElementsByTagName("h3")(0).innerText
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Search Form(Google)").Cells(y, 4).Value = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("r")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
            
        For x2 = 1 To 9
            
            y = y + 1
            
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Search Form(Google)").Cells(y, 3).Value = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("r")(x2).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getElementsByTagName("h3")(0).innerText
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Search Form(Google)").Cells(y, 4).Value = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("r")(x2).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
            
        Next x2
            
        IE.Quit
        Set IE = Nothing    
    
    Next y
```

Comment: try one with an error test, if it fails do the other.

Comment: Quite a broad question to answer but the different browsers will have some compatibility differences with HTML depending on what elements are used in the source code. I found this out when having problems with using IE in compatibility mode (which runs in IE 6 i think it was). You will need to have a better understanding of which elements aren't supported in IE9 and work it out from there.

Comment: No offense, but even IE11 is already EOL (End Of Life) and has problems with some pages. IE9 is a relic from Win XP days. Even Win XP is EOL. So if IE cannot be upgraded to V11, the operating system is also outdated and should not be used with access to the Internet. The cause of your problem is the supported DOM level (Document Object Model). Via the DOM a browser manages the structure of a page internally. If Google is not your real target, you can try using an XMLHttpRequest instead of IE. If you need to process dynamic content (does not work with XMLHttpRequest), have a look at Selenium.